# Function overloading with externally defined types for arguments

Tags: typescript

I would like to use function overloading to provide type hints. My overloads are using external types for the arguments though, which is why I always get the error provided in the comment of the following snippet:

```
// Chart.ts
import { gaugeConfig, type GaugePayload } from './gauge'
import { lineConfig, type LinePayload } from './line'

export type ChartDefaultBuilderFunction = (payload: any) => EChartsOption
export type SeriesType =
  | 'line'
  | 'lines'
  | 'gauge'

const ChartDefaults: Partial<Record<SeriesType, ChartDefaultBuilderFunction>> = {
  gauge: gaugeConfig,
  line: lineConfig,
}
export function buildChart(type: 'gauge', payload: GaugePayload): EChartsOption
export function buildChart(type: 'line', payload: LinePayload): EChartsOption
export function buildChart(type: SeriesType, payload: any): EChartsOption {
  if (ChartDefaults[type] == null) throw new Error(`Configuration not implemented for chart type ${type}`)
  return ChartDefaults[type]?.call(null, payload as any) as EChartsOption
}

// Gauge.ts
/**
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: "line", payload: LinePayload): EChartsOption', gave the following error.ts(2769)
index.ts(22, 17): The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
*/
const storage_gauge = buildChart('gauge', {
  gaugeColor: '#086939',
  gaugeMax: 0,
  gaugeValue: 0,
})
```

I don't really get why typescript has an issue with this, since my types are exported...It'd work fine if I just used `object` as type, but I would like to use my own types.

I appreciate any help, I hope I did not forget to provide anything important.

Comment: So what's the error on Overload 1 of 2?

Comment: @kikon There's no error for the overload 1 of 2, that's the weird thing. It only shows the error on the second one, and if I add another overload in between it will always show the same error on the most last overload

Comment: That never happened to me :) Is is related to exporting and importing, or do you get the same error if you append the last lines to the first file (`chart.ts`)?

Comment: @kikon It only happens if they are not in the same file, the error is gone if I put it all in one file :/ it's really strange...

Comment: Do you have a link to a web IDE or something you can provide as a [mre]? Right now we can't really begin to reproduce this so it's hard to diagnose and fix it.

Comment: @jcalz I tried replicating this error in a repl, but wasn't successful with it. This might be some tsconfig or even an IDE issue actually, I guess I'll have to investigate this further.